# Design tips for waiting for a user input while working on another thread

Tags: multithreading, user-interface, asynchronous-programming, qt

I am working on an application with multiple threads (using Qt, C++). One of this threads is designed to execute a batch of operations like reading/writing from/to files as well as creating new ones. Sometimes, while this worker thread is active, I need some sort of confirmation from the user for operations like overwriting a file; I was thinking about doing this by emitting a signal from the worker and waiting for a response from the UI thread, which will show a popup and then give back the result; but I think this is an anti-pattern for asynchronous programming.

Are there any good, safe patterns to manage a problem like this?

Answer (score 1):

Any sort of cross thread communication may become problematic. Try storing the user input in a common place and have the worker thread pole for a value in the common place periodically and act based on that.

Answer (score 1):

Obviously, when you're doing this, you are essentially forcing the threads to synchronize, thus - as you say - defying the whole point of having separate threads. Yet, if those confirmations are rare, that may still be quite acceptable, and `Qt::BlockingQueuedConnection` is one really convenient way to handle inter-thread communication in that case.

Presumably, though, your main worry is keeping the UI alive, while actually, the user *is* expected to wait for the worker thread to do its thing. Depending on the details of what your worker thread is actually doing, you may want to look into `QCoreApplication::processsEvents()` as an alternative approach. This would allow you avoid threading, altogether. (This approach assumes that you will have an opportunity to call `processEvents()` regularly, during the task, of course.)